# How to override methods decorated @overload?

Tags: python, overriding, overloading

I made a class inheritted QGraphicsItem (of pyside6) and wrote two overridings.

```
from PySide6.QtCore import QRectF, QLineF, QPointF
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QGraphicsItem

class myItem(QGraphicsItem):
    def setPos(self, x: float, y: float):
        # do something and the coordinates maybe changed
        super().setPos(x, y)
    
    def setPos(self, pos: QPointF):
        # do something and the coordinates maybe changed
        super().setPos(pos)


item = myItem()
item.setPos(10, 10)
print(item.pos())
item.setPos(QPointF(100, 100))
print(item.pos())
```

But I get an error when I run the script.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\MyProjects\GitRepo\projects\test2.py", line 15, in <module>
    item.setPos(10, 10)
TypeError: setPos() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

When I checked the definition of `QGraphicsItem`, the `setPos` methods had an `@overload` decorator.

```
@overload
def setPos(self, pos:Union[PySide6.QtCore.QPointF, PySide6.QtCore.QPoint, PySide6.QtGui.QPainterPath.Element]) -> None: ...
@overload
def setPos(self, x:float, y:float) -> None: ...
```

How could I make it right..?

Comment: Python doesn't have overloaded functions. The `@overload` decorator is intended to provide multiple sets of *type hints* for a single function.

Comment: @chepner  couldn't overridden function provide multiple sets of type hints?

Comment: It can, but you can still only provide *one* definition of the function. For example, you'll probably see an undecorated definition like `def setPos(self, x=None, y=None, pos=None):` or `def setPos(self, **kwargs):`, which in its body examines the values of the arguments it receives to figure out which "version" is being called. The decorated functions are only there for the benefit of the type checker.

Comment: Take a look at the source of the `overload()` decorator — there may be some clues. There might even be some documentation: `help(PySide6.overload)`.

Answer (score 0):

At the expense of installing another package you could achieve what you are trying to do. These libraries will re-direct to methods based on the type signature of the method definition.

e.g. [plum](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/plum-dispatch) and [multidispatch](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/multipledispatch).

This example is with plum.

```
from plum import dispatch


class MyClass:
    pass


class MultiDispatch:

    @dispatch
    def func(self,
             a: int) -> str:
        print(f'ex1. Type {type(a)}')
        return str(type(a))

    @dispatch
    def func(self,
             a: str) -> str:
        print(f'ex2. Type {type(a)}')
        return str(type(a))

    @dispatch
    def func(self,
             a: int,
             b: str) -> str:
        print(f'ex3. Types {type(a)} - {type(b)}')
        return str(type(a))

    @dispatch
    def func(self,
             a: str,
             b: int) -> str:
        print(f'ex4. Types {type(a)} - {type(b)}')
        return str(type(a))

    @dispatch
    def func(self,
             a: MyClass) -> str:
        print(f'ex5. Type {type(a)}')
        return str(type(a))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    m = MultiDispatch()
    print(m.func(123))
    print(m.func('456'))
    print(m.func(MyClass()))
    print(m.func(123, '456'))
    print(m.func('456', 123))
    print(m.func(MyClass()))
```

This give the result below, where you can see the calls to the same method name are redirected to the method with the matching type signature. Including where one of the type signatures depends on a user defined class.

```
ex1. Type <class 'int'>
<class 'int'>
ex2. Type <class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
ex5. Type <class '__main__.MyClass'>
<class '__main__.MyClass'>
ex3. Types <class 'int'> - <class 'str'>
<class 'int'>
ex4. Types <class 'str'> - <class 'int'>
<class 'str'>
ex5. Type <class '__main__.MyClass'>
<class '__main__.MyClass'>
```

I cannot test it, but I believe your code would work as you want if trivially modified to below.

```
from plum import dispatch
from PySide6.QtCore import QRectF, QLineF, QPointF
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QGraphicsItem


class myItem(QGraphicsItem):
    @dispatch
    def setPos(self, x: float, y: float):
        # do something and the coordinates maybe changed
        super().setPos(x, y)

    @dispatch
    def setPos(self, pos: QPointF):
        # do something and the coordinates maybe changed
        super().setPos(pos)
```